# Menu Items not found in Menustrip pywinauto

Tags: pywinauto

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
import pywinauto



app = Application(backend="win32").connect(title_re="Trader*").top_window()
app.MenuStrip1.print_control_identifiers()
```

here is print control output of menustrip

```
WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.33c0d9d - 'MenuStrip1'    (L-1280, T-10, R0, B14)
['WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.33c0d9d', 'MenuStrip1WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.33c0d9d', 'MenuStrip1']
child_window(title="MenuStrip1", auto_id="mainMenu", control_type="System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip")
```

[Image of Menustrip in application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKsZD.png)

Not able to select Menu Items Live file

In Swappy also menustrip has no childrens.
Here is swappy image of app connected
[Image of Swappy of Connected app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdyaM.png)

How to select menus like 'file->log in' in such situation.

Comment: Expanded submenu is usually a top level window which not intuitive way. This is .NET.

Comment: I tried it.. changed backend win32 to uia it worked.

Comment: OK, please post this solution as an answer and accept it (gray check box at the left side of answer should work for you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed backend win32 to uia it worked.